# Changing all variables to specific naming convention (lowercase)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any automated way to change all variables (alongside there references) in file to specific convention (lower case) without changing the whole line to lowercase?

I'm using VScode IDE but it doesn't seem to help, it only helps in changing them one by one!

In my case

```
local Device_MacAddress_f =     ... >> local device_macAddress_f
local Device_Signalstate_f=     ... >> local device_signalstate_f
local Device_Controller_f =     ...
local Device_Timesinceboot=     ...
local Device_Ipaddress_f =      ...
local Device_Subnetmask_f =     ...
local Device_Gateway_f =        ...
local Device_Netbiosname_f=     ...
local Device_Dhcpstate_f =      ...
local Device_Fwversion_f =      ...
local Device_Kernalversion=     ...
local Device_Controllertype_f = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable regex search <kbd>.*</kbd>

Search: `local Device_([A-Z])`

Replace: `local device_\l$1`

Comment: First step is to open the Find Widget: `Ctrl+H` with the Replace field open.